Flowbite components are visable, but not working in Livewire/Laravel
I successfully installed Flowbite by following the docs https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/laravel/. Components only works if I test in the global layout, but they do not work in any other component. Any thoughts why Flowbite is not working while using global layout which includes scripts and stylings?
resources/cs/app.css:
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

resources/js/app.js:
import './bootstrap';
import "flowbite";

views/components/layouts/app.blade.php:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>{{ $title ?? 'Page Title' }}</title>
    @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
</head>

<body class="container mx-auto p-4">
    {{ $slot }}
 // If I use Flowbite components here, they work
</body>

<style>
    body {
        background: #232946;
        font-family: 'DM Sans', sans-serif;
        font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    }
</style>

</html>

tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./resources/**/*.blade.php",
    "./resources/**/*.js",
    "./resources/**/*.vue",
    './node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js'
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      textColor: {
        primary: '#fffffe',
        secondary: '#b8c1ec',
        accent: '#232946',
      }
    },
    plugins: [
      require('flowbite/plugin')
    ]
  },
}


What you mean with "they do not work" ? Are they not displaying as expected or not interacting correctly?  (e.g. the javascript is non executed) -- Livewire rewrites the DOM and event listeners set by other javascript libraries are often lost

They are displaying as expected, but javascript is not working. Is there a solution to stop livewire rewriting the dom in this case?

The options can be 2 + 1 *** you can try to detect when Livewire wrote the DOM and reinitialize the Flowbite elements, but this isn't always possible or can be complicated. *** you can add wire:ignore to the elements managed by Flowbyte, but Livewire can't more interact with them and you have do it with plain JS. ***
you can abandon Flowbyte and do the same things with AlpineJS (this is my preferred option). However, it is not possible to give a precise answer without seeing the code
